simultaneous non linear equations
$x^3y^3(x^3+y^3) = 905$ and $x^4y^4(x+y) = 810$. Find values for x and y.
Divide the first equation by the second equation, and factor to give $(x+y)^2 = \frac{25}{6}$. If I had stopped at this point, then I would believe that the desired factors are $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$. However, they are not.
Continuing and using substitution gives $(\frac{3}{2^{1/3}}$, $2^{2/3})$ and
$(2^{2/3}, \frac{3}{2^{1/3}})$ as the factors of the two original equations.
Is my approach of dividing the original equations an error?

$(x^3 + y^3)/(x+y) = x^2 - x y + y^2$.  Where do you get $(x+y)^2$?

Is there a typo? Your "solutions" with $2^{2/3}$ are no solutions, but close to the solution. So may be, there is a typo with $905$.

Yes, there is a typo. The desired solutions arise for $945$ instead of $905$. You can use the resultant.

Please check once more the two given values $905$ and $810$, then kindly confirm the (new) values. Then there is a lot of unclear information about getting $(x+y)^2$, please make this point clear, a potential answer has to type more and also pass through this or a similar step. Which are the "desired factors" and what does it mean $(2,3)$ or $(3,2)$? Which factors of which factorization are here considered. Continuing what and using which substitution do we get the next pair (that we have to guess)?

The resultant of the two polynomials $f(x,y)=x^3y^3(x^3+y^3)-905$ and $g(x,y)=x^4y^4(x+y)-810$ is given by
$$
r(x,y)=2835769176x^{18} - 5491269405905x^9 + 451887258369600.
$$
This is a quadratic equation in $z=x^9$. Its roots are the solutions of the system of equations $f(x,y)=g(x,y)=0$. So we obtain exactly two real solutions, one with $x=2.30689122393$, and one with $x=1.64063811316$. Note that none of them is $2^{2/3}$.
Edit: Taking $945$ instead of $905$, we obtain the desired solutions with $2^{2/3}$. In fact, then the resultant is given by
$$
r(x,y)=(4x^6 + 54x^3 + 729)(x^6 + 4x^3 + 16)(2x^3 - 27)(x^3 - 4).
$$

Yes, your approach of dividing directly is an error because you are not going to eliminate a variable that way.
Entering the equations into Geogebra gives symmetric intersection points when x and y are 1.640638... and 2.30689...
These are close to the answers you came up with, so perhaps you have made a simple mistake

These are exactly my solutions, see below. You can compute them with the resultant. Perhaps there is a typo in the exercise (very likely).

My error it should have been 945.  I gather that not eliminating a variable by division is
not a  appropriate strategy - thanks.
